# Best writing app for phone?

Tags: software, mobile

I'm currently using Google doc for writing, but I've noticed recently that it is very slow to use (it takes a few seconds for my words to appear on screen) It is very frustrating. My book has reached 100+ pages so that could be the reason behind it.

Is there a writing app that could easily handle large documents?

I would prefer one that I can access from multiple devices (phone, pc) and has cloud save.

Comment: If a big file is slow, could you use several smaller files and work on one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

yWriter is a good programm for writing. It has a desktop Application, an Android and iOS App (and even a Kindle app). The costs are around 4,79€ in the [Google PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spacejock.ywriter&hl=de) in Germany.

You have the possibility to synchronize your apps with Google Drive and Dropbox. I use it every day and work in the evening at home and in the daytime on mobile. The integration is seamless and you just have to remember to quit one app, if you switch to the other (lost a whole chapter because I worked on it on my way and didn't closed it at home ... home version had overwritten the mobile save)

But the app itself is pretty good

Comment: How is it at handling large files?

Comment: You organize your book in a single file, divided in Chapters and Scenes. For myself I'm about 80k words and it handels it perfectly. But it should be able to organize books up to 500k words or more